# SQL Server tracking changes in data coming from Oracle link

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a SQL Server table that I create by selecting from an Oracle view using a database link. The Oracle database is fully wrapped and comes from an external vendor.

The table has a text field for the current month's update. It doesn't have any dates or IDs. When I run the procedure to get the data I don't have any idea if the value has been the same for the last few months or had been updated, I have no idea when it was updated. I thought of going through the query row by row and detecting if the value is there and if it isn't, insert a new row with a creation date. This will provide a monthly row with any updates, keeping the older updates linked to the correct date. Maybe. I'm no expert and couldn't think of a way. Would this break? How would you solve my problem?

I don't have DBA rights in any databases.

Comment: `I thought of going through the query row by row and detecting if the value is there and if it isn't, insert a new row with a creation date` yes this sounds like an approach when you dont have any rights..also it is not clear on what your data looks like and what you are trying to compare and why not use primary key

Comment: @TheGameiswar the data is a view from a 3rd party company's software, I don't have access to the query or the base tables... This idea makes sense